# How do I enumerate a 2-dimensional NumPy array excluding the first and last rows and columns?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I would like to enumerate the elements of a 2-dimensional NumPy array excluding the first and last row and column (i.e. the ones in the matrix below).

```
import numpy as np

q = np.zeros((4, 4))
q[1, 1] = 1
q[1, 2] = 1
q[2, 1] = 1
q[2, 2] = 1

# [[0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I can enumerate every element using and add conditionals checking to the first and last row/column but this seems crude:

```
for ij, q_ij in np.ndenumerate(q):
    print(ij, q_ij)
```

When I slice off the first and last columns and rows `i` and `j` are off by one

```
for ij, q_ij in np.ndenumerate(q[1:-1, 1:-1]):
    i, j = ij
    original_ij = (i + 1, j + 1)
    print(original_ij, ij, q_ij)

# (1, 1) (0, 0) 1.0
# (1, 2) (0, 1) 1.0
# (2, 1) (1, 0) 1.0
# (2, 2) (1, 1) 1.0
```

I can obviously adjust `i` and `j` to properly refer to the original matrix. For the sale of clarity, I am attempting to calculate the laplacian for a scalar field (e.g. temperature)

```
laplacian[i][j] = q[i+1][j] + q[i-1][j] + q[i][j+1] + q[i][j-1] - 4*a[i][j]
```

and need to avoid the boundary elements.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the array with sliced assignment:

```
In [164]: arr = np.zeros((4,4),int)
In [165]: arr[1:3,1:3] = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)
In [166]: arr
Out[166]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Since you print each element, a double loop on the desired indices is just as good as `ndenumerate` (or anything else that 'hides' the indexing):

```
In [167]: for i in range(1,3):
     ...:     for j in range(1,3):
     ...:         print(f'({i},{j}) {arr[i,j]}')
     ...: 
(1,1) 1
(1,2) 2
(2,1) 3
(2,2) 4
```

There's nothing elegant about printing the elements of an array one by one with coodinates.

### edit

```
q[i+1][j] + q[i-1][j] + q[i][j+1] + q[i][j-1] - 4*a[i][j]
```

can rewritten with slices as something like this (defails may not be right)

```
q[2:4,1:3] - q[0:2,1:3] + ... - 4*a[1:3, 1:3]
```

What I'm aiming for is a 2d extension of the basic difference calculation:

```
In [178]: x = np.array([1,0,3,2,0,1])
In [179]: x[1:] - x[:-1]
Out[179]: array([-1,  3, -1, -2,  1])
```

This is what `np.diff(x)`.

In `scipy.signal` there's a `convolve` function that may be applicable.  I've seen others use it, but haven't myself.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no more "elegant" form, sincerely, I will use the basic range(1,q_ij-1)* , but all is our programming manner at the end, just do it with the form that youre more confortable and works well

*range(start, stop[, step])*